# How can i query data between start and end date from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I need show data between start and end date from firestore collection. As far as, I know I cant query two different fields according to firestore docs. So how can I achieve this?

[image: Collection structure here!]

I did a workaround for the moment but I don't know if this is the right way to filter something or not.

Streambuilder:

```
 StreamBuilder(
            stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Schedule')
                .where("Schedule_Employees",
                    arrayContains: "$Employee_NAME")
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                ((context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
```

My Workaround for now:

Here inside Listview builder I'm comparing the selected-Date from UI to the Start and End Date.And returning the data based on bool value.

```
 Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
            streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                       
  .............. ......////// WORKAROUND   ////////.............................
        String strDt = formattedDate;
        DateTime Selected_Date =
            DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(strDt);
        DateTime start_Date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(
            "${documentSnapshot['Schedule_Start_Date']}");
      
        DateTime End_Date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(
            "${documentSnapshot['Schedule_End_Date']}");
       
        dateCheck() {
          bool chk;
          if (Selected_Date.isBefore(start_Date)) {
            print('before start so cant show');
            return chk = false;
          } else if (Selected_Date.isAfter(start_Date) &&
              Selected_Date.isBefore(End_Date)) {
            //  print(dt1.isBefore(dt2));
            print('between start and end date ');
            return chk = true;
          } else if (Selected_Date.isAtSameMomentAs(
                  End_Date) ||
              Selected_Date.isAtSameMomentAs(start_Date)) {
            print('sameee ');

            return chk = true;
          } else if (Selected_Date.isAfter(End_Date)) {
            print(
                'Selected Date is after end date so cant show');
            return chk = false;
          } else {
            chk = false;
          }
          return chk;
        }  
      return dateCheck()     
            ? NewWidget(
                kbackgroundwhite: kbackgroundwhite,
                documentSnapshot: documentSnapshot)
            : const SizedBox();
      }),
);
```

Comment: You say you did a workaround. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yea, it solved my problem. But i don't think its the right way to achieve this kind of functionality. I'm looking for other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Range filters are [allowed on one field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries:%7E:text=Range%20filters%20on%20only%20one%20field), not multiple fields. For your query, you would need to setup an index since it would be a compound query against more than one value (an array query and a date query). I just ran the query in the query builder on the firestore page and was able to query using something akin to:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Schedule')
                .where("Schedule_Employees",
                    arrayContains: "$Employee_NAME")
                .where("timestamp", isLessThan: someFutureTimestamp)
                .where("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: somePastTimestamp)
                .snapshots()
```

Have you tried a query like this against your database? If this works, it should save on costs of reads from the database, whereas your workaround looks like it loads all documents and then does client side filtering.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I just saw your document structure, you are correct that one dimension ranges are supported. I was under the assumption that your time field was in one field only.

Comment: No problem mate, your answer might help someone in the future.